# Filtering duplicates in an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have got an array of arrays like so:

```
[
  [ 48, 28 ], [ 36, 19 ],
  [ 54, 12 ], [ 24, 12 ],
  [ 30, 12 ], [ 42, 12 ],
  [ 40, 10 ], [ 48, 4 ],
  [ 12, 4 ],  [ 18, 3 ],
  [ 20, 2 ],  [ 36, 1 ]
]
```

I would like to filter duplicates based on the first value of each item: `item[0]`. For instance, for the array above I would like to remove `[48, 4]` and `[36, 1]` from it because it already includes `[48, 28]` and `[36, 19]`. Thanks by advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over `data` using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) while having a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the first number as `key` and the item as `value`. In each iteration, if the map doesn't have the first number as a key, add the record. In the end, the `values` of this map will be your expected result:

```js
const data = [
  [ 48, 28 ], [ 36, 19 ],
  [ 54, 12 ], [ 24, 12 ],
  [ 30, 12 ], [ 42, 12 ],
  [ 40, 10 ], [ 48, 4 ],
  [ 12, 4 ],  [ 18, 3 ],
  [ 20, 2 ],  [ 36, 1 ]
];

const res = [...data.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  const [first] = arr;
  if(first && !acc.has(first)) acc.set(first, arr);
  return acc;
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could take a closure over a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the array by looking to the first items of the nested arrays.

```js
const
    data = [[48, 28], [36, 19], [54, 12], [24, 12], [30, 12], [42, 12], [40, 10], [48, 4], [12, 4], [18, 3], [20, 2], [36, 1]],
    result = data.filter((s => ([v]) => !s.has(v) && s.add(v))(new Set));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Find this one a bit cryptic... I'll dig it. Thanks.

Comment: there is no hiding function behind. it takes a set for `s` and returns a function for `filter`. inside, it checks for the value and adds the value, if not exists.

Answer (score 2):

You could cache the first occurrences then filter based on value by key.

```js
const data = [
  [ 48, 28 ] , [ 36, 19 ],
  [ 54, 12 ] , [ 24, 12 ],
  [ 30, 12 ] , [ 42, 12 ],
  [ 40, 10 ] , [ 48,  4 ],
  [ 12,  4 ] , [ 18,  3 ],
  [ 20,  2 ] , [ 36,  1 ]
];

const initial = data.reduce((acc, [key, value]) =>
  ({ ...acc, [key] : acc[key] ?? value }), {});

const filtered = data.filter(([key, value]) => initial[key] === value);

console.log(filtered.map(JSON.stringify).join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Alternatively, you could populate a set as you filter:

```js
const data = [
  [ 48, 28 ] , [ 36, 19 ],
  [ 54, 12 ] , [ 24, 12 ],
  [ 30, 12 ] , [ 42, 12 ],
  [ 40, 10 ] , [ 48,  4 ],
  [ 12,  4 ] , [ 18,  3 ],
  [ 20,  2 ] , [ 36,  1 ]
];

const filterByUniqueKey = (data, fn) => {
  const keySet = new Set();
  return data.filter(item => !keySet.has(fn(item)) && keySet.add(fn(item)));
}

const filtered = filterByUniqueKey(data, ([key]) => key);

console.log(filtered.map(JSON.stringify).join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is no JS method to do this explicitly but that does not mean you can't write your own.

The obvious solution would be to create a dictionary with the keys being the numbers in the 0th index and the values being the numbers in the 1st index.

If they key already exists its a dupe and you may delete that entry.

This is not an optimal solution but will work

Comment: Upvote for not posting code here. The question is like "Here is my code, make it work" and your answer encourages him/her to implement their own solution based on a hint, not code.

Comment: @MartinSeeler This is not serious stuff, just the final step of a problem I was trying to solve on Codewars. I wasn't able to wrap my head around that final step, was curious about how others would be able to solve this, so I just asked here...

Comment: @chalatum I see, hope you got it now. 
> was curious about how others would be able to solve this
This is why https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ exist. Post your solution there and ask for feedback

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my solution will be more simple to understand.

```js
let arr = [
  [ 48, 28 ], [ 36, 19 ],
  [ 54, 12 ], [ 24, 12 ],
  [ 30, 12 ], [ 42, 12 ],
  [ 40, 10 ], [ 48, 4 ],
  [ 12, 4 ],  [ 18, 3 ],
  [ 20, 2 ],  [ 36, 1 ]
]
const simpleArr = [];

const indexOfUnuniqueEl = [];

//detect ununique elements index and push them into arr
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
if(simpleArr.includes(arr[i][0])) {
indexOfUnuniqueEl.push(i);
}

//push only first number to array
simpleArr.push(arr[i][0])
}

//return only unique element with indexOfUnuniqueEl indexes array 
arr = arr.filter(function(e, i){
    return indexOfUnuniqueEl.indexOf(i) < 0;
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only challenge for doing this vs. getting unique values in the array in general is that you're only using one part of the array (the first number). You can just keep track of those as you `filter`, for instance in a `Set`:

```
const seen = new Set();
const filtered = original.filter(entry => {
    // Get the key for this entry
    const key = entry[0]
    // New one?
    const flag = !seen.has(key);
    if (flag) {
        // Yes, add it
        seen.add(key);
    }
    // Return the flag
    return flag;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const original = [
  [ 48, 28 ], [ 36, 19 ],
  [ 54, 12 ], [ 24, 12 ],
  [ 30, 12 ], [ 42, 12 ],
  [ 40, 10 ], [ 48, 4 ],
  [ 12, 4 ],  [ 18, 3 ],
  [ 20, 2 ],  [ 36, 1 ]
];

const seen = new Set();
const filtered = original.filter(entry => {
    // Get the key for this entry
    const key = entry[0]
    // New one?
    const flag = !seen.has(key);
    if (flag) {
        // Yes, add it
        seen.add(key);
    }
    // Return the flag
    return flag;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: *(Misread the question initially. If you see `.join(",")` above, hit refresh.)*

Answer (score 0):

The previous solutions work fine, but a this can also be accomplished with an additional array and using the ternary operator:

```
let previousElements = []
    myArray.forEach((element, index) => {
    (!previousElements.includes(element[0])) ? previousElements.push(element[0]) :  myArray.splice(index, 1)
});
```

Which translates to:

```
myArray.forEach((element, index) => {
//If we haven't crossed the element yet, add it to the previous elements array
if(!previousElements.includes(element[0])){
    previousElements.push(element[0])
}

//If it has been seen, remove it
else{
    myArray.splice(index, 1)
}});
```